# Apache Tika Docker Image on Google Cloudrun (Heapsize Issue)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, heap-memory, apache-tika, google-cloud-run, tika-server

I am trying to run the Apache Tika server on Google Cloud Run. These are the steps followed:

1. I copied Apache Tika's Docker image from DockerHub onto GCP Artifactory using the command
   gcrane cp apache/tika:1.24.1-full us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/resume-ai-frontend/tikaserverrepo/tikaserver
2. I was able to deploy the Tika's docker image onto Cloudrun as well.

However, when i try to run some Curl commands, I see that I encounter Heap Size error as below.

```
> Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238029Z at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238034Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238040Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238044Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238049Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238055Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238059Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238064Z at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238069Z at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Default
2021-03-21T02:54:22.238074ZCaused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Error
2021-03-21T02:54:22.239728ZPUT500359 B631 mscurl/7.64.0 https://apachetikaserver1241-h6hycic72q-ue.a.run.app/meta/content-type
```

The details of the error message as reported in GCP is as below:

[image]

The curl commands on google cloud shell include:

```
curl -T 'Aaddhar Paul.docx'  https://apachetikaserver1241-h6hycic72q-ue.a.run.app/meta/content-type
```

The capacity allocated is also sufficient i believe

[image]

Please advise how do I improve the heapsize for Tika?

Comment: 512 MB of memory is probably the issue. Allocate more memory.

Comment: This seems like an answer. Can you post it as a real answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 0):

As John Hanley said in a comment, the probably issue is the memory and it is a good solution to allocate more memory.